# Angularjs how can change color of currency symbol

Tags: angularjs

Hi sameone have an idea if there is a way to change the color of currency filter symbol ? example : i would like to have the value in black and the dollar symbol in red color
Thank you

Comment: I think you need to create a custom filter, that combine the native angular's `number` filter, plus your addition of a currency symbol that you will wrap inside a `<span class="custom-currency"></span>` - This will allow you to style it using CSS (Example: `.custom-currency { color: red; }`)

Comment: hi alon eitan sorry i dont understand your idea

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters), specifically the `customCurrency` example - You can extand it by making a similar filter that will return the currency where the symbol is wrapped (Possible format: `{{ amount }}<span class="custom-currency">$</span>`). You can combine it your custom filter the [number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) for formatting the actual amount using js (`$filter('number')(number, fractionSize)`)